# Cartoon or Anime with space western vibes features young boy in a place with adults with prosthetics coveting the boy's organs

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I only remember a small part of this cartoon/anime, I think from the 80's or 90's but maybe even early 2000's. I would have watched this in the UK on TV possibly late 90's or very early 2000's.

I remember a terrified young lad in an inn/bar possibly in space.
The lad was taken there/kidnapped? At the bar all the adults were armed with guns/blasters and all had one or some kind of prosthetic eyes, limbs etc. They were eyeing the lad up as a source of replacement body parts.
Felt gritty and bleak or post apocalyptic.

Ruled out *BraveStarr* from other questions.

Comment: Was this a series or a movie? Also, roughly how old would you say the boy was?

Comment: I think it may be a series but it could well be a movie but I didn't realise. The boy is around 10 years old I think but could be pre-teen or early teens.

Comment: Can you remember what channel you saw this on?  In the UK the SciFi channel on Sky/cable showed a lot of anime during the late 90s.
From your description I'd guess this was more adult oriented than for kids?

Comment: It would have definitely been on Sky. I can't remember what channel though. I used to watch a lot of Cartoon Network but you are right it did feel more adult orientated so not ruling out another channel.

Answer (score 4):

As you don't mention superheroes (which would make me say [*"SilverHawks"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SilverHawks)) or mechas ([*"Saber Rider and the Star Sheriffs"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saber_Rider_and_the_Star_Sheriffs)), the combination of "western vibes" and artificial bodies points me to [*"Galaxy Express 999"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Express_999).

The franchise comprises, besides the original manga, an anime series originally aired in Japan from 1978 to 1981 (and later distributed and dubbed worldwide) and several movies that retell and continue the story.

In particular, you might be remembering the very first episode of the series, in which young kid Tetsuro confronts Count Mecha's band of robotic criminals that previously killed his mother.
According to the [episode list page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Galaxy_Express_999_episodes), there are also other episodes in which Tetsuro and/or Maetel (the woman he travels with on the space train) are kidnapped.

Comment: [Episode 1 on dailymotion](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x83r78a): the scene you may be remembering starts at about 12:18.

Comment: Very close to Galaxy Express but I don't think that's it either. The boy and style of animation is very close. The scene I remember in the bar has a lot more adults including female characters. The prosthetics I remember were less pronounced, one or two things per character like only an eye or a limb. The atmosphere in the bar was tense but jovial which changed once the boy appeared. With regards to the organs thing, it felt like the boy was one of the only humans without prosthetics/implants left, so a natural source of body parts the rest were coveting.

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[Starchaser: The Legend of Orin](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090065/)*** (1985)...?

> Set on the subterranean Mine-World, a band of human worker are treated like slaves under the power of the evil overlord Zygon until one, Orin, unearths the hilt of a mythical sword that only he can master. Escaping the planet, he runs into the rogue smuggler Dagg and a pair of helpful droids and the princess, who all team up to return to the Mine-World with a plan to defeat Zygon and free Orin's enslaved people.

This isn't a perfect match by any means. The protagonist, Orin, isn't that young -- I'd guess he's meant to be about 17 or so -- and the scene takes place in a swampy area rather than a bar or inn. That said, he is captured by a group of cyborgs known as Man-Droids, who tie him between two trees and argue over who'll get which of his body parts. This part of the story is described in the [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starchaser:_The_Legend_of_Orin):

> Orin digs a tunnel to the surface of Trinia, where he is later captured by Man-Droids, a group of decaying half-organic, half-robotic beings who intend to tear him apart and use his body parts to replace their own.

In regard to the film's genre, it feels heavily influenced by *Star Wars* to me, and therefore has space western vibes to the same extent that that franchise does. Orin is the film's equivalent of Luke Skywalker, and there are also equivalents of Han, Leia and Vader.

You can view part of the scene with the Man-Droids in the video clip below, beginning at around the 0:42 mark.

Comment: Sorry definitely not Starchaser : The legend of Orin. Orin is too old for what I remember.